# How to keep Tinymce Editor active after submitting form

Tags: tinymce, textarea

I'm using Tinymce Editor on my website but when I submit the form I got input data without textarea. So, my question is how to keep the textarea with Tinymce Editor after submitting the form?

Looking for your answers guys.

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are in PHP, you can put the post data back in the textarea.
Something like this:

```
<form method="post" action="yourpage.php">
    <textarea name="content">
    <?php
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        echo $_POST['content'];
        }
    ?>
    </textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

Comment: I did that but I still have the same problem. I think that I need to do something in tinymce.init() but I don't know what to do.

Comment: Looks like tinymce is configured properly. I think the problem is either in your form or in the way you try to repost form data.
Try if it works with tinymce disabled.
It would be also helpful for us to see the rest of your code.

Comment: You are right! Thanks the problem is in my php script. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Great to hear I could help you with your problem. In that case please condiser accepting my answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code:

```
tinymce.init({
                mode: "exact",
                elements: "zone_textarea_mceEditor",
                plugins: [
                    "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
                    "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
                    "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste codemirror responsivefilemanager"
                ],
                toolbar1: "undo redo | bold italic underline | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | styleselect",
                toolbar2: "| responsivefilemanager | link unlink anchor | image media | forecolor backcolor  | print preview code ",
                image_advtab: true,
                autosave_ask_before_unload: false,
                height: 200

    });
```

Also, you can find bellow the image before and after submit the form:
[image: Before submit the form]

After:
[image: After submit the form]

What I'm looking for is the keep the first layout after submitting the form.